# VBA define beginning and ending of a Macro (strings) for each section?

Tags: vba, excel

[image: The example of my table Excel]

Hello , how can I define an Interval based on strings and that loops into it ? 
for example to define from 1 start -- to 2 end,  and then move to the other interval ?
This is to search for a name "xx" for example in each interval and show with msgbox the adress of cell .

I did the following code , the problem is that I don't know how to make that interval .. can someone help me please ? Thanks.

```
Sub search_for_names()

    lastligne = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("students").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastligne
        Set rnginformation = Cells(i, 1)
        Set rngaction = Cells(i, 2)
        If rnginformation = "1" And rngaction = "start" Then
            MsgBox "beginning of interval"
            For k = 1 To rnginformation = "2" And rngaction = "end"    'define the end of interval
                MsgBox "x"
                Set actionAnalyse = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("students").Cells(k, 2).Find(xx, LookIn:=xlValues)
                firstAddress = rngaction.Address
                MsgBox firstAddress
            Next k
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: if you just want to look for a certain name in a dynamic range there are better and faster ways, like you can use `Match` , `Find`, `VLookup`. What exactly do you want your code to do ?

Comment: I did use Find in this code . What i want is a macro that loop in each section from 1 start -- to 2 end and search for "xx" name , as you can see , i didn't succeed to define the ending of the loop @Shai Rado

Comment: is it important to loop each 1 start - to 2 end individually ? or is it also OK  to loop through the entire worksheet and return the address of all cells with "xx" name at once ?

Comment: yes ! it is really important to loop each 1 start - to 2 end individually , i didn't know how to devise it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find your starting row set a variable equal to i `lStart = i`.  Then when you find the last row build your range from the starting row to i `.Range(.Cells(lStart, 2), .Cells(i, 2))`.  Since you actually want the rows in between lStart and i `.Range(.Cells(lStart + 1, 2), .Cells(i -1, 2))` would be more efficient.

```
Sub search_for_names()
    Dim i As Long, lastligne As Long, lStart As Long
    Dim actionAnalyse As Range, rSearch As Range

    With Sheets("students")
        lastligne = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastligne

            If .Cells(i, 1) = "1" And .Cells(i, 2) = "start" Then lStart = i

            If .Cells(i, 1) = "2" And .Cells(i, 2) = "end" Then

                Set rSearch = .Range(.Cells(lStart, 2), .Cells(i, 2))

                Set actionAnalyse = rSearch.Find("xx", LookIn:=xlValues)

                If Not actionAnalyse Is Nothing Then

                    MsgBox actionAnalyse.Address

                End If
            End If

        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you , this is very helpful !